# consuming c++ object in json and getting http put response in json, example code errors,REST API

Tags: c++, json, linux

I got the following code from internet. I expect it to print contents of post request of any URL.It is printing ->Added new Id: {"listOfAssets":[{"assetName":"Gold Asset"}]}->which is correct.I guess this is a string output. I want output in json which I need to convert to C++(serialize) Can someone advice what more should I do?I am running the code in linux environment.1st let me know how to get json output.serializing can be done later. To do this I added 2lines
It is giving me errors
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'web::http::http_exception'
  what():  Incorrect Content-Type: must be textual to extract_string, JSON to extract_json.

```
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <pplx/pplxtasks.h>
#include <cpprest/json.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cpprest/details/http_constants.dat>
#include <cpprest/http_msg.h>


using namespace std;
using namespace web;
using namespace web::json;
using namespace pplx;
using namespace web::http;
using namespace web::http::client;
using namespace web::http::details;

pplx::task<int> Post()
{
  return pplx::create_task([]
  {
    json::value postData;
    postData["name"] = json::value::string("Joe Smith");
    postData["sport"] = json::value::string("Baseball");

    http_client client("http://54.191.233.99:8080/sparkAPIs/testing.html");
    return client.request(methods::POST, "",
      /*postData.serialize().c_str(),*/ "application/json");
  }).then([](http_response response)
  {
    if(response.status_code() == status_codes::OK)
    {
      //auto body = response.extract_string();
      //std::cout << "Added new Id: " << body.get().c_str() << std::endl;
      auto body = response.extract_json();
      body.get();
      //return std::stoi(body.get().c_str());
    }

    return 0;
  });
}

int main()
{
        cout<<"hello world"<<endl;
        Post().wait();
}
```

Comment: Can this code really listen to  www.zoho.com port 80?  Otherwise the line you commented out could be your issue.

Comment: the zoho.com page is opening in the browser, so, I thought my code should get the contents of their post method. We have a simmilar  post service developed by other persons that is not ready yet. So, as per you, I shall wait for them

Comment: yes the new url worked , now I am looking to get output in json than what I got aS STRING

Comment: I suggest stepping with a debugger and seeing what this code is doing after the request arrives.